# Connecting to SQL Server 2017 with remote computer isn't working

Tags: sql-server, tcp, sql-server-2017

I'm not able to connect to my SQL Server 2017 that is installed on my desktop from any remote computers.

Here are the steps and actions I have taken:

I followed all troubleshooting steps on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine#testing-a-local-connection

- Turned off windows firewall on both computers (to eliminate this)
- Tested tcp by connecting on the same computer as the server with `tcp:localhost` and I was able to connect
- Used a port check tool to make sure the port was open

SQL Server remote connections allowed: http://prntscr.com/gvb1gb

SQL Server tcp/udp turned on: http://prntscr.com/gvb2yh

Router settings showing port forwarding is configured: http://prntscr.com/gvb3jm

I ran out of ideas and I don't know what else to do to connect to this sql server from a remote computer. Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try next?

UPDATE: I added port forwarding for 1434 udp in addition to the 1433: http://prntscr.com/gvbd01

Comment: SQL Server Browser Service + port 1434: `To communicate with the SQL Server Browser service on a server behind a firewall, open UDP port 1434 in addition to the TCP port used by `

Comment: You mentioned port forwarding.  Can you connect from another computer on the same network?  Did you check the port from another computer on the same network?

Comment: lad2025 I just updated my post to show the new port forwarding for port 1434 as well

@DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'm not able to connect from another computer on the same network but I was able to run the port check tool and both 1433 and 1434 just time out when I check them but my second sql server which is on port 55739 is also not open when I check from another computer on my local network